# React pass onMouseHover to Children component

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a small react component called react-hover in it's [V2](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover/tree/feature/version2.0) version.

This lib just simply enable user to define their trigger and hover component and make the hover component appear when mouse hover on trigger component.

```
    <ReactHover
      options={optionsCursorTrueWithMargin}>
      <ReactHover.Trigger>
        <TriggerComponent />
      </ReactHover.Trigger>
      <ReactHover.Hover>
        <HoverComponent />
      </ReactHover.Hover>
    </ReactHover>
```

Now I am facing an issue of passing the `onMouseHover` events to the children component in tigger component:

```
 render () {
     return (
     <div
        onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver.bind(this)}
        onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut.bind(this)}
        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove.bind(this)}
        onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart.bind(this)}
        onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd.bind(this)}
    >
    {this.props.children.props.children}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Because only the children component can tigger the hover component, but in above implementation, it is binding the listeners to the parent div, so I met the issue that parent div's css width is more than the childen's width, so when mouse is on the div ( not in the children) the hover component show up. But I cannot control the children component's inner code as it is passed in as children.

I am just wondering how to tackle this issue?

The example code is [here](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover/blob/feature/version2.0/src/example/Example.js).
The place where bind the mouse event is [here](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover/blob/feature/version2.0/src/lib/Trigger.js#L12)

Just wondering what's the solution for this?
how to bind those events to the children component when cannot put code in children component.

Below is showing when mouse outside of trigger component still can trigger the hover component.

[image]

Comment: You can make the parent div wrap the children exactly using css, so that your trigger component and children behaves as one. As this is a plugin for others to use, for them Trigger will be a children wrapper. Allow them to pass styles for the parent container if you wish to.

Comment: @sahil how to wrap the children using css? in my code, I wrap it but seems the parent div have slightly larger width

Comment: you can take the width of the immediate child and apply that to the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

Just resolved by add ref to the container and retrieve Children's width:

```
let childStyles = this.refs.triggerContainer.children[0].style
```

and apply to the current parent container.

check this [code](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover/blob/master/src/lib/Trigger.js)